# Como buscar a maior data no MongoDB junto com outros parâmetros?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Tenho um `schema` que contem data, *status* e código:

```
var entregaSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        codEntrega: String,
        placaPipa: String,
        codRota: String,
        codMA: String,
        dataMA: Date,
        localMA: String,
        codPA: String,
        dataPA: Date,
        localPA: String,
        statusEntrega: String,
        cadEntrega: Date
});
```

Gostaria de varrer este esquema e trazer a maior data para o `codPA` passado e com *status* a 3 que seria finalizado.

Tipo: para o `codPA = 34`, onde existir maior data e *status* = 3, isso será executado num `for` para cada `PA`, 1,2..34 e ao encontrar vai realizar outra função de inserir uma nova entrega para este `PA` se caso um calculo de tempo em relação a ultima data trazida com um tempo passado. Tipo, se `dataPA >= 7` Inserir entrega para este `codPA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o Aggregation framework do mongodb para fazer isso.

Utilizando o mongoose, seria mais ou menos assim:

```
// Troque essa linha pelo seu mapeamento
var entregaModel = mongoose.model("entrega", entregaSchema); 

entregaModel.aggregate([

    // Filtra para apenas os documentos com status = 3
    { $match: { statusEntrega: 3 }, 

    // Desses documentos, junte todos os que tem codPA iguais
    // E salve a maior dataPA em "maiorData"
    { $group: {
        _id: "$codPa",
        maiorData: { $max: "$dataPA"  }
    }}

], function (err, result) {
    if (err) 
        console.log(err);
    else
        // Sai a lista de todos os codPA e a data deles
        // já filtrados pelos com status = 3
        console.log(result);
});
```

Para saber mais sobre o framework aggregate do mongodb, dá uma lida nesse link: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/

A api do aggregate no mongoose fica nesse link: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate

Espero ter ajudado